# How to format runtime error message on laravel job - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am currently using laravel job to insert data from csv file to the database. And, the code is as:

```
try{
    //insertCode

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->error_arr[] = $e->getMessage();
    $this->error_row_numbers[] = $this->data['row_value'];
}

$this->data['row_value'] = $this->data['row_value'] + 1;
```

Here, I have used try catch block, so whenever it encountered any runtime error, it catch error message and also store row_numbers. So that later, I could send the details about on which row this error occured.

The flow is working totally fine, its just the error message that I want to format. Basically there could occur two types of error.

`the value could be empty`
`the value could be in different format`.

Currently,it throws message like:

**for empty record**

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'initial_amenity_value' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `amenity_values` (`amenity_id`, `initial_amenity_value`, `amenity_value`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3103, , , 2020-03-26 20:12:16, 2020-03-26 20:12:16))
```

**for worng format**

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'initial_amenity_value' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `amenity_values` (`amenity_id`, `initial_amenity_value`, `amenity_value`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3105, , , 2020-03-26 20:12:16, 2020-03-26 20:12:16))
```

How could I format this message to something like: `Empty value initial_amenity_value`,`wrong format on initial_amenity_value`

Comment: can u post the migration?

Comment: @TsaiKoga `$table->increments('id');
$table->double('initial_amenity_value');
$table->double('amenity_value');
$table->unsignedInteger('amenity_id');
$table->foreign('amenity_id')->references('id')->on('amenities')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->timestamps();`